# java regex add trailing slash

Tags: java, regex, magnolia

I am trying to redirect the urls to add trailing slash

```
/news -> /news/
/news?param1=value1 -> /news/?param1=value
/news#anchor?param1=value1 -> /news/#anchor?param1=value1
```

I need to do it through a regex that identifies only the path and add /. When there are no parameters there is no problem.

`^(/[a-z0–9/_\-]*[^/])$  -> $1/`

But when there are parameters I am not able to create the regular expression that separates the path from the parameters.

Any ideas?, thanks

Comment: The `$` in your regex matches the end of the input (or a line in multiline mode), so it isn't going to match any url with path parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be just need to extend the end of string past the parameters.
To cover both with and without parameters might be:

`^(/[a-z0–9/_-]*(?<!/))([^/]*)$` -> `$1/$2`

see https://regex101.com/r/Iwl23o/2

Comment: It has worked perfectly, I have only added that it also accepts capital letters. Thank you very much, I was already going crazy with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't match the end of the string with `$` and there is no need for `[^/]` at the end either.

```
^(/[a-z0–9/_\-]*)
```

```js
const regex = new RegExp("^(/[a-z0–9/_\-]*)");
console.log("/news".replace(regex, "$1/"));
console.log("/news?param1=value1".replace(regex, "$1/"));
console.log("/news#anchor?param1=value1".replace(regex, "$1/"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you tried matches only `/news` because the anchor `$` asserts the end of the string.

If you omit the anchor, it would also match the `?` and `#` as you use `[^/]` which matches any char except a forward slash.

---

You could repeat 1 or more times matching a forward slash followed by 1 or more times any char listed in the character class to prevent matching `///`

In the replacement use the full match and add a a forward slash.

```
^(?:/[a-z0-9_-]+)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7G082y/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/STSHGO)

```
String regex = "^(?:/[a-z0-9_-]+)+";
String string = "/news\n"
     + "/news?param1=value1\n"
     + "/news#anchor?param1=value1";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
String result = matcher.replaceAll("$0/");

System.out.println(result);
```

Output

```
/news/
/news/?param1=value1
/news/#anchor?param1=value1
```

**Note** that in your regex, the `hyphen` in this part `0–9` is

<sup>https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2013 instead of https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002D</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String[] arr = { "/news", "/news?param1=value1", "/news#anchor?param1=value1" };
        for (String s : arr) {
            System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("([^\\/\\p{Punct}]+)", "$1/"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
/news/
/news/?param1=value1
/news/#anchor?param1=value1
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

- `(`: Start of capturing group#1

  - `[`: Start of [character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)

    - `^`: None of

      - `\/`: A `/` character
      - `\p{Punct}`: A [punctuation character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
  - `]`: End of character classes
  - `+`: [One or more times](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)
- `)`: End of capturing group#1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very simple regex like this:

```
^([/\w]+)
```

With this replacement string: `$1/`

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/VsBlLL/1)**

[image]